# fnupdate updates wrong row datatables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to update a row by passing index.

http://live.datatables.net/raculubo/1/

But it most of the time replaces a wrong row.

The code is :-

$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var index = table.column(0).data().indexOf("Cedric Kelly");
console.log("index2",index);
table.row().data(["ax","by","dd"], index);

} );

Comment: Some notes in case they help: (1) You only need one "document ready" function. (2) You only need one `var table = ...` statement. (3) Be careful when using `$('#example').DataTable()` vs `$('#example').dataTable()` - they mean two subtly different things (see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for details). (4) It's not mandatory, but it is preferable to use the modern names for functions - so, instead of the old `fnUpdate()`, use `row().data()` (see [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for details).

Comment: can you check now....it still behaves the same. Just try to replace the names & it edits different rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of how you are sorting your data, leading to a difference between the "sort order" index and the "internal DataTables" index.

The `table.column(0).data()` function will return an array of names, as currently displayed in the table, taking into account sorting. In this scenario, the index of "Cedric Kelly" is therefore `1`.

However, the *internal unique index value stored by DataTables* is actually `3` because that is the order provided to DataTables from your HTML code when the data was loaded for the very first time (where Cedric Kelly is the 4th record listed - so the index is `3`).

This initial loading happens before data is sorted, and it is during this step that data indexes are assigned. Once assigned, they never change (unless you delete data).

Your data update function uses the value of `1` - thus updating the wrong row.

The fix for this is to tell DataTables to use the original loading order in the `table.column(0).data()` function:

```js
var index = table.column(0, {order:'index'} ).data().indexOf("Cedric Kelly");
```

That directive `{order:'index'}` causes DataTables to use the original loading order. Now, the correct record will be updated because this `index` will now return `3` instead of `1`.

You can see more details about this "selector modifier" syntax [here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier).

Bear in mind that the correct syntax for updating a row is actually this:

```
table.row( index ).data(["ax","by","dd"]);
```

Finally, bear in mind that if you filter your data, then you are OK, since the default value used is `search: 'none'` - which means "do not take searching/filtering into account" when selecting the column data.